# How can I model the mentioned JSON to java object using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson2

I want to model the below JSON to java object. The number of regions are dynamic.

```
{
  "regional": {
    "asia-pacific-east": 0.01667,
    "asia-pacific-southeast": 0.01245,
    "australia-central": 0.01633,
    "australia-central-2": 0.01633,
    "australia-east": 0.01313,
    "australia-southeast": 0.01313,
    "brazil-south": 0.01382,
    "canada-central": 0.01142,
    "canada-east": 0.01142,
    "central-india": 0.01233,
    "europe-north": 0.01222,
    "europe-west": 0.01279,
    "france-central": 0.01256,
    "france-south": 0.01519,
    "japan-east": 0.01359,
    "japan-west": 0.01359,
    "korea-central": 0.01199,
    "korea-south": 0.01039,
    "south-india": 0.01405,
    "united-kingdom-south": 0.01256,
    "united-kingdom-west": 0.01256,
    "us-central": 0.01211,
    "us-east": 0.01074,
    "us-east-2": 0.01074,
    "usgov-arizona": 0.01279,
    "usgov-texas": 0.01279,
    "us-north-central": 0.01074,
    "us-south-central": 0.01211,
    "us-west": 0.01336,
    "us-west-2": 0.01074,
    "us-west-central": 0.01211,
    "west-india": 0.01233
  }
}
```

Comment: If it is dynamic then your json should be in array form

Comment: Used gson? 
gson.fromJSon(yourjson,POJO.class)

Comment: Haven't used jackson in a long while, but for what I remember you can map it to a `Map` (so the `regional` field is an instance of Map, or write your own deserialiser if you want that in  a nicer structure.

Comment: consider changing your json design

Comment: I can't modify the JSON as I am getting it from a third party website

Comment: HAve you tried using gson?

Comment: No I haven't tried Gson. But that's not a constraint. I can use it if I can get the desired model. Could you please tell me how to do it in Gson ?

Comment: If your JSON is dynamic, you should be dealing with an array. What have you tried till now and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved with Gson instead of Jackson. I am modelling my classes as below. 

`public class Data {`

```
private Map<String, Double> regional;

public Map<String, Double> getRegional() {
    return regional;
}

public void setRegional(Map<String, Double> regional) {
    this.regional = regional;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
```

}

And I can fetch the data as below

`Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class); System.out.println(data.getRegional().get("asia-pacific-east"));`